# I am using Alfresco 5.0.d Community Edition and mysql as database. I am creating user through Admin Tools -> Users -> Create User

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using Alfresco 5.0.d Community Edition and mysql as database. I am creating user through Admin Tools -> Users -> Create User. But when I am trying to invite these users, they are not searchable. They are also not searchable in People section but they are searchable in Admin Tools -> Users.

No error is coming in server logs.
I have even deleted previous indexing and created new indexing many times.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have they accepted their invitations yet?

Comment: Not even getting option to generate invitations.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would help. It may be that you are looking in Site Members, which is meant to show the people who have already been invited and accepted their invitation. If you want to invite people to a site you need to click Invite Users. Then you should be able to search the users you've already created.

Comment: Try creating a test user and logging in with that user for the first time and see if that helps?

Comment: I have finally solved the problem, the issue was solr4 indexing and I was resetting the solr indexing (My bad). It somehow got corrupted and was creating the error. But thanks anyway for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by changing a property in alfresco-global.propeties file

```
### Solr indexing ###
index.subsystem.name=solr4
```

to

```
### Solr indexing ###
index.subsystem.name=solr
```

This issue is related with indexing.