# user is not visible in people finder but that user is visible in site in alfresco

Tags: alfresco-share

A new user has logged into Alfresco, and joined the new site that we created. I can see that user as a member of that site, but can't find him in People Finder and can't add him to a site from the Administrator dashboard.Is it a indexing problem ?.we are using 4.2.2 version.If its a indexing problem what we need to do?it happened in prod.

Comment: It could be, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751853/i-am-using-alfresco-5-0-d-community-edition-and-mysql-as-database-i-am-creating.

Answer (score 0):

try to invoke the people's webscript "api/people" by your browser and check the user's properties.

Comment: data is coming.checked other users data and this user data and they are same.do we need to do solr4 re indexing?